# gitlab CI/CD Connection timed out

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I've been trying to setup CI/CD to my EC2 server. Private key is added to variables but still i can't connect to server. Could someone advise?

Here is mine before_script code:

- 'which ssh-agent || ( apt-get install -qq openssh-client )'
- eval $(ssh-agent -s)
- echo "${SSH_PRIVATE_KEY}" | tr -d '\r' | ssh-add - > /dev/null
- mkdir -p ~/.ssh
- '[[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config'

SSH connection code:

- ssh ubuntu@$SERVER_IP

Error code:

- ssh: connect to host ****** port 22: Connection timed out

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're not able to connect at all. Have you opened the security group on the EC2 instance for incoming traffic on port 22? Unfortunately the IP range used by GitLab CI is the [entire GCP IP range](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/gitlab_com/#ip-range), so you'll probably have to whitelist that.

Depending on your security requirements, it might be worthwhile to look into using [SSM](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ssm/start-session.html) instead. Connecting or running commands via SSM saves you from configuring any security group rules or managing any SSH keys. It does require you to have awscli + AWS credentials available to your GitLab runner instance however.

Comment: Thanks! I've forgot to change EC2 security group! It was enabled to connect via SSH only with my IP. Thanks!